# zbar get QR rotation

Tags: rotation, qr-code, zbar

I am scanning using Zbar in Windows in a number of images (the are all portrait images) and the QR code is being read perfectly well, irrespective of whether the QR code itself is portrait or landscape.  Is it possible to get the info from ZBar whether the QR code itself is portrait or landscape on a particular scan as we need that for filing?